# Swift: 'Rank? does not have a member named 'simpleDescription'?

Tags: enums, switch-statement, swift, option-type

I keep getting an error on the lines in my code below:

```
let rank1desc = rank1Conv.simpleDescription();
let rank2desc = rank2Conv.simpleDescription();
```

that claims that 'Rank?' does not have a member named 'simpleDescription'. I find this odd as I wrote this code according to Apple's tutorial and haven't implemented and optionals anywhere as the Rank? suggests that I have. I'd love to know why it's giving me this error and where the optional is coming from if one does indeed exist. Thank you so much!

Here is my code:

```
enum Rank: Int{
   case Ace = 1;
   case Two = 2, Three = 3, Four = 4, Five = 5, Six = 6, Seven = 7, Eight = 8, Nine = 9, Ten = 10;
   case Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13;

   func simpleDescription() -> String{
       switch self{
       case .Ace:
           return "Ace";
       case .Jack:
           return "Jack";
       case .Queen:
           return "Queen";
       case .King:
           return "King";
       default:
           return String(self.toRaw())
       }
   }
}

let ace = Rank.Ace;
let aceRawValue = ace.toRaw();

 func compRank(rank1: Int, rank2: Int) -> String{
    let rank1Conv = Rank.fromRaw(rank1);
    let rank2Conv = Rank.fromRaw(rank2)
    let rank1desc = rank1Conv.simpleDescription();
    let rank2desc = rank2Conv.simpleDescription();

    if(rank1 > rank2){
        return rank1desc;
    }
    else if(rank2>rank1){
        return rank2desc;
    }
    else{
       return "They are equal";
    }
}

compRank(rank1: 3, rank2: 2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `fromRaw` does not produce a `Rank`, but rather `Rank?` (an optional of type `Rank`). `simpleDescription` is a part of `Rank` and not `Rank?`. You need to extract the `Rank` value from it (and test that a value is present) in order to access `simpleDescription`.

If you can guarantee that `compRank` will always be called with valid values, the easiest way of fixing your code is by replacing these lines:

```
    let rank1Conv = Rank.fromRaw(rank1);
    let rank2Conv = Rank.fromRaw(rank2)
```

...with this:

```
    let rank1Conv:Rank! = Rank.fromRaw(rank1)
    let rank2Conv:Rank! = Rank.fromRaw(rank2)
```

The `!` tells the compiler that the type of `rank1Conv` (and `rank2Conv`) is an optional, but you're guaranteeing that it does indeed contain a value. The compiler will then let you treat it like a `Rank` and implicitly extract the value as needed.

However, this is defeating the safety you get with optionals. If the method were called with the values (999,888) for example, the optional values returned by `fromRaw` would be `nil`, and  it would cause a runtime error if you tried to use them. You should redesign this method to more properly take advantage of optionals, which I'm too tired to do right now.